# Backup (export, merge) all contacts form Samsung Galaxy S5

Tags: contacts, backup, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I have tried to backup all the Contacts from Samsung Galaxy S5 to PC using Smart Switch, but it did not backup any contacts since they are all linked to either GOOGLE or EXCHANGE accounts.

What is the most straightforward way to backup **all the contacts** from the Samsung Galaxy S5 regardless on what account they are linked to? Like to merge all the EXCHANGE contacts to the GOOGLE account.

The reason for backup is the fact, that Exchange account used for the contacts expires soon. What happens to the contacts that are linked to the Exchange account when the account is deleted from the phone?

Comment: Have you tried to 1) start the *contacts* app, then 2) tap the menu button/overflow-menu and 3) select *Import/Export* to export your contacts to [VCard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vcard) format? That can be used in the same place to re-import – and is well understood by most desktop PIMs.

Comment: Not really, I have expected more straightforward way for such a smartphone like S5 or S6, like to merge one account into another and sync contacts there. I also do not quite understand why the linked account cannot be changed for a contact and why there can be only one account for a contact. Hope some day everything around contacts and contacts replication gets standardized.

Comment: You didn't ask that – and I have no clue how more "straight forward" it could be. That export should include *all* contacts from your phone. I suggest you try that first to verify (I've never used an Exchange account, so I cannot tell for sure concerning that part). As for the "linked account cannot be changed": The Exchange server probably cannot talk to the Google server – so you cannot "change the type" here, but have to "move the contacts" ;)

Comment: Right, thanks for the suggestion. Changing the link would delete contact in one account and create in another - but I only imagine that

Comment: I'd think so, too: as long as both "storages" have the same fields, it should work that way. But I guess the contacts app cannot know that, so information *might* be lost that way. Not allowing for that hence could be a security measure. I don't know for sure, though – just imagining.